# Как реализован цикл событий (event loop) в браузере?

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, webbrowser, event-loop

На просторах интернета не удалось найти статей на эту тему. Очень подробно расписано, как устроен цикл событий в NodeJS, и почти ничего про браузер.

Имеется в виду цикл событий, с помощью которого реализуется асинхронное программирование на JS. В случае, когда окружением, в котором выполняется JS-код, является Node, цикл событий запускается средствами встроенной библиотеки libUV, которая обращается к операционной системе, которая запускает цикл. Но как это происходит в браузере? Поделитесь, кто знает.)

Comment: чет вы плохо искали, куча статей ведь, из последнего https://habr.com/company/oleg-bunin/blog/417461/,  там и про браузер

Comment: Держи два видео [Первое](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8cV4ZvHXQL4) и [Второе](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=1&v=j4_9BZezSUA)

Comment: А разве есть разница? Тот же libevent, не?

Comment: Да вот как ни странно, именно про это - не куча. Спасибо за ссылку, но там тоже тема не раскрыта. Да, нарисован event loop и упомянуто про таски и их приоритеты, но хотелось бы знать, как и когда запускается этот event loop, и что он делает, когда тасков нет. Одним словом, в подробностях.

Comment: @Eeki, event loop - это просто высокоуровневая концепция, движок v8 вообще не знает, что такое event loop и в его сурсах вы не встретите это слово нигде. есть 2 класса `TaskQueue` и `TaskRunner`, `TQ` - содержит в себе контейнер `queue<Task>` из `STL` c++, `TR` - имеет 2 публичных метода `PostTask и PostDelayedTask`, `PT` - подготавливает таск для запуска, `PDT` - подготавливает таск через какой-то промежуток времени, есть также класс `Platform` который проверяет длину очереди каждый раз - когда call stack пустой, приоритеты расставляет v8, но за запуск тасков в другом потоке отвечает libuv

Comment: Большое спасибо за видео, - первое, второе и третье. Не полностью, но многое прояснилось.

Comment: Насколько удается понять, цикл событий в браузере реализуется движком рендеринга браузера (иногда называют модулем отображения). Движок рендеринга браузера при открытии веб-страницы создает главный поток - (он же цикл событий?), в котором выполняется JS-код и рендеры страницы. Поправьте, если где-то ошибаюсь.

Comment: @Eeki, нет, главный поток - это адресное пространство всего вашего js кода и цикл событий не имеет отношения к браузеру, он реализован на уровне движка, то, как устроен цикл событий в node.js, точно также и в браузере, v8 используется как и в ноде, так и в хроме, для того, чтобы понять такие вещи недостаточно видео о рендеринге в браузере, рендеринга нету в движках

Comment: @overthesanity, помимо видео о рендеринге я просмотрела еще кучу видео и практически все текстовые источники на тему.  И во всех них единогласно пишут - цикл событий не является частью движка V8, а является частью окружения, в котором выполняется код. Поэтому никак не могу согласиться с вашим утверждением.

Comment: @Eeki, https://medium.com/@arturbasak/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-event-loop-%D0%B2-libuv-67f5c7c8574f

Comment: @Eeki, что по вашему использует под капотом nodejs и что такое окружение в котором выполняется код?

Comment: @overthesanity, насколько мне известно, Node это движок V8 + библиотека libuv. Окружением, в котором выполняется код, может быть либо браузер, либо Node. В статье, на которую вы ссылаетесь, в самом начале приведен кусок кода, где с помощью libuv "инициализируется структура событийного цикла". То есть в Node он реализован средствами библиотеки libuv, а не движка. libuv, в свою очередь, использует средства операционной системы (вот, например, если это Windows: https://habr.com/post/159201/).

Comment: а в случае, если окружением является на Node, а браузер, цикл событий является частью браузера (https://habr.com/company/ruvds/blog/340508/). Но - нигде не нашла почти никакой информации, когда и как запускается этот цикл, разве что вот в этой лекции: https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=1&v=j4_9BZezSUA от @Alexander Zaytsev пара слов была о том, что веб-страница - это главный поток, и потом сразу же переход к циклу событий, что навело меня на мысль, что главный поток = цикл событий.

Comment: @Eeki, libuv - это API написанное на языке Си, когда гугл делает релиз новой версии V8 по semver - они объединяют код, написанный на языке С++ с другими зависимостями, такими как libuv, этот этап жизненного цикла называется `embedding`, node это не v8 + libuv, это многопоточная скомпилированная программа с кучей библиотек внутри, нет никакого окружения, js => AST => байткод => машинный код, везде этот процесс одинаковый, только `output` платформозависимый, изучите для начала многопоточность, а только потом начните копать event loop, по другому никак, все эти статьи - поверхностное объяснение